# How to add parameter to method and to overrides in child classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, resharper

C#, Visual Studio 2013, ReSharper 8.2.

I have a class. This class is inherited by other classes, all within the same solution. The class has a protected constructor that takes three parameters. Each child class introduces a public constructor with the same parameters, chained to the constructor in the parent class.

I want to add a fourth parameter to this constructor. I want this new parameter to be added to the constructor in every child class. I don't want to add it to the child classes manually because there are many.

How can I use Visual Studio or ReSharper to do this automatically? Usually R# would make this obvious but not this time.

Comment: How do you override the constructor?

Comment: @AliSepehri.Kh Thank you, reworded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just upgraded to ReSharper 9, so I can't check in the previous version, but here's how I managed to do it in the latest version:

- First I manually added the parameter to the base constructor.
- Then I opened the `Alt+Enter` menu and selected *Apply change signature refactoring...*

[image: Apply change signature refactoring...]

- In the dialog I selected *Resolve with call tree*

[image: Resolve with call tree]

- Now the *Refactoring - Change signature* dialog opened with all derived classes requiring the fix:

[image: Refactoring - Change signature]

- I only had to click the second option (*Create parameter ... in constructor ...*) to fix all the occurences:

[image: Create parameter ... in constructor ...]

Comment: Thanks for brilliant explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you can use `Change Signature` refactoring of Resharper. For more information See [This](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/changesignature.html).